# Replacing inheritance of widgets by composition without creating lots of boilerplate code

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance, widget

I have implemented a generic `SelectionListScreen` widget that displays a *ListView* with *CheckboxListTiles* where the user can select elements out of a given list of entities and press a *FloatingActionButton* to perform some action on them. Pretty straight-forward. I want this to be a basic class that can be extended in some way to add additional features, e.g. assigning different colors to the captions and checkboxes based on properties of the named entities.

```
class SelectionListScreenState<E extends NamedEntity> extends State<SelectionListScreen> {
  static const listEntryStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);

  late final List<E> _sortedEntities;
  List<bool> _isBoxSelected = [];
  int _selectedBoxesCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _sortedEntities = widget.namedEntitySet.toSortedList() as List<E>;
    _setBoxSelections(_sortedEntities.length, true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MtAppBar(context),
      body: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, _) => Divider(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemCount: _sortedEntities.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return buildRow(context,
              entity: _sortedEntities[i], isChecked: _isBoxSelected[i], onChanged: _onListTileChanged(i));
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: 
    // (...)
```

Originally, I had a subclass `HighlightSelectionListScreen` with an accompanying `HighlightSelectionListScreenState`. All I had to do was to override the `buildRow()` method of `SelectionListScreenState` to replace the basic *CheckboxListTiles* by whatever I want.

---

Now the Flutter language dev team has been pretty clear that **composition should always be prefered to inheritance** when extending widgets. I have read some discussions where some people made the point that extending widgets may make sense in certain scenarios. However, I wanted to follow the language dev team's recommendation, so **eventually I refactored my code**.

I am pretty unhappy with the result, as it creates a lot of boilerplate code. I had to copy all attributes of `SelectionListScreen` to `HighlightSelectionListScreen`, just so I can pass them to the nested `SelectionListScreen` in its `build()` function; whereas in the inherited version I just had to pass the constructor parameters to the super constructors.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myproject/structs/named_entity.dart';
import 'package:myproject/structs/unique_named_entity_set.dart';

import 'selection_list_screen.dart';

// Extension of the generic SelectionListScreen that highlights
// or disables certain checkbox list tiles
class HighlightSelectionListScreen<E extends NamedEntity> extends StatelessWidget {
  static const normalEntityColor = Colors.black;
  static const highlightEntityColor = Colors.indigo;
  static const listEntryStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);

  final UniqueNamedEntitySet<E> namedEntitySet;
  final PreferredSizeWidget appBar;
  final String mainButtonLabel;
  final Function(BuildContext, List<E>, List<bool>, int) onMainButtonPressed;
  final Function(E) doHighlightEntity;
  final Function(E) doDisableEntity;

  const HighlightSelectionListScreen(
      {super.key,
      required this.namedEntitySet,
      required this.appBar,
      required this.mainButtonLabel,
      required this.onMainButtonPressed,
      required this.doHighlightEntity,
      required this.doDisableEntity});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SelectionListScreen(
        namedEntitySet: namedEntitySet,
        appBar: appBar,
        rowBuilder: _buildRow,
        mainButtonLabel: mainButtonLabel,
        onMainButtonPressed: onMainButtonPressed);
  }

  Widget _buildRow(E entity, bool isChecked, Function(bool?) _onListTileChanged) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
        title: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(style: listEntryStyle.copyWith(color: _getEntityColor(entity)), children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: entity.name,
          ),
          if (doHighlightEntity(entity))
            WidgetSpan(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
                    child: doDisableEntity(entity) ? Icon(Icons.check) : Icon(Icons.update)))
        ])),
        activeColor: _getEntityColor(entity),
        enabled: !doDisableEntity(entity),
        selected: isChecked,
        value: isChecked,
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        onChanged: _onListTileChanged);
  }

  Color _getEntityColor(E entity) => doHighlightEntity(entity) ? highlightEntityColor : normalEntityColor;
}
```

It's a mess. Every single property has to be mentioned 3 times in the composition version (constructor, class attribute, build function), vs. 1 time in the inheritance version.

Am I missing something and there is a more elegant way to do this? Or could this be a case where using inheritance on widgets might actually be legitimate?